# fcm auth error in post request

Tags: php, firebase, curl, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

i got a app using fcm to notificantions and all works fine when i send messages via the console, but when i try to send via php(curl post) or postman(firefox extension) i got a auth error(even using the key)

string(304) "{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } "

i got the key from the firebase project console
my php code is

```
  public function send_FCM(){
// Method - 1
$fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/anal.........719/messages:send';
$notification = array(
  "to"=>"/topic/cidade396",
  "notification"=>array(
    "body"=>"test 123"
  )
);
 $headers = [
    'Authorization: key=AIz.........9KWwy5BisxXYbA8',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($notification));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
return true;
```

}
anyone know how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Legacy FCM* uses the key you're getting from the Firebase console. With **FCM v1**, which is what you're using, you use more secure credentials created from a service account key. You download the service account in the Firebase console under Project Settings>Service Accounts and click "Generate new private key". See the [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) for more info. PHP directions for getting credentials are [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts)

The format will be

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
```

But it will not work for the API Key. You'll need to pass the Google credentials which you can find out how to generate in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The example in the  documentation for [authorizing HTTP v1 send requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_v1_send_requests) shows the Authorization header value starts with `Bearer` not `key=`:

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer AIz.........9KWwy5BisxXYbA8',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];
```

Comment: i tried now with Bearer and Bearer key= but dind't worked

Comment: Just `Bearer` not `Bearer key=`

Comment: How are you getting the access token? Using the instructions in the documentation I linked in my answer?  It is not the server key used in the legacy API (from Clouding Messaging tab of Project Settings).